# Unable to remove Spring Kafka logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How can I change the logging for Springboot Kafka? I'm seeing over 2M messages on our Splunk server and nothing is working:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler=ERROR
logging.level.org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler=ERROR
org.apache.kafka=ERROR
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=ERROR
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator=ERROR
logging.level.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator=ERROR
logging.level.root=OFF
```

also tried:

```
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.org.apache.*=ERROR
```

Dependencies:

```
    kafkaVersion = "2.1.1"
    log4jVersion = "2.11.1"
    springBootGradlePluginVersion = "2.4.2"
    springBootVersion = "2.3.0.RELEASE"
    springJdbcVersion = "5.2.5.RELEASE"
    springWebVersion = "2.3.4.RELEASE"
```

```
        // Logging
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14"
        implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:$log4jVersion"
        implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:$log4jVersion"
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2', version: "$log4jVersion"

        // Spring Dependencies
        compile group: "org.springframework.kafka", name: "spring-kafka", version: "$springBootVersion"
        compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-jdbc", version: "$springJdbcVersion"
        compile(group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web", version: "$springWebVersion") {
            exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic"
            exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        }
```

None of this does anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925737/spring-boot-logging-to-kafka-how-to-eliminate-warning-best-practices

Comment: `logging.level.org.apache.kafka=OFF`? But def see the other stuff in that Q linked. ^

Comment: You are missing nothing. Properties usually work fine - so something unusual is in your environment - please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) someplace, that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: @GaryRussell I've added the log dependencies I'm using. I'm not sure the best minimum example I can post aside from dependencies.

Comment: What about the boot starters? - show all the deps - Boot uses LogBack by default. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.custom-log-configuration

Comment: @GaryRussell I've added the rest of the deps. Wondering if this is strange or not.

Comment: The current Boot 2.3 version is 2.3.11 (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn); Boot 2.3.x pulls in spring-kafka 2.5.x (see the matrix here https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) you shouldn't be using the Boot version there, use Boot's dependency management (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-dependency-management) so the correct versions of each dependency is pulled in properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected for me:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.11.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api"
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2'

    compile(group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic"
        exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    }

    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```